# Mongodb ruby driver: edit Collection::View instance filter

Tags: ruby, mongodb

When I create Collection::View instance with:

```
client = Mongo::Client.new('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test')

view = client[:users].find( { name: "Sally" } )
=> #<Mongo::Collection::View:0x69824029475340 namespace='test.users' @filter={"name" => "Sally"} @options={}>
```

How I can change `filter` hash of this instance later? This does not work:

```
view.filter.merge!("age" => 30)
=> #FrozenError: can't modify frozen BSON::Document
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. `.filter` is a method which takes arguments.  It is not a hash.
See [examples](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/master/examples/query.rb) 
and also search [the code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/search?q=def+find&unscoped_q=def+find)

However you might be able to do something like:

```
view = lambda { |hash|  client[:users].find(hash) }

search_params = { name: "Sally" }

view.(search_params)

view.(search_params.merge!({foo: 'bar'}))
```